# Make function for workflow - Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, parallel-processing, workflow

I'm trying to speed up script for checking disk SMART prefail status, because I need to check two thousand computers.
However the script is still writing out status for the same disk - computers "hostname1" and "hostname2" has different disks.

```
function disk-status (){
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$computername
            )
                $WMI = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive
                ForEach ($Drive in $WMI){
                $disk = $Drive.Caption
                $status = $Drive.Status
                #condition will be changed to "-notmatch"
                if ($status -match "OK"){
                        #I'm using write-output to see if the script works during testing
                        Write-output $computername $disk $status
                        }
                }
}



workflow Get-disk-status {
    param(
    [string[]]$computers
  )
    foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers) {        
        disk-status -computername $computer

  }
}

#in the final version I'm going to use get-adcomputer
$computers = "hostname1", "hostname2"

Get-disk-status $computers
```

Output I get:

```
hostname1
ST500LM0 21-1KJ152 SCSI Disk Device
OK
hostname2
ST500LM0 21-1KJ152 SCSI Disk Device
OK
```

Can anybody give me at least a hint how to fix it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try changing `$WMI = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive` to `$WMI = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName $computername`

Comment: You need to pass the computer name to `Get-WMIObject`. Like so: `$WMI = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName $computername`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
$WMI = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive
```

to

```
$WMI = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName $computername
```

It looks like it may be retrieving information from the machine you are on because you haven't passed a computer to the `Get-WMIObject` cmdlet.

Comment: Thank you all! At first I tried `$WMI = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive -Computername $computer` which was wrong...Your explanation also helped me to understand little more of writing functions - thank you once more!